# How many steps did I walk?

Tags: code-golf, array

A simple pedometer can be modeled by a pendulum with two switches on opposite sides—one at x=0 and one at x=***l***. When the pendulum contacts the far switch, the ambulator can be assumed to have taken half a step. When it contacts the near switch, the step is completed.

Given a list of integers representing positions of the pendulum, determine the number of full steps recorded on the pedometer.

#### Input

- An integer ***l***>0, the length of the track.
- A list of integers representing the positions of the pedometer's pendulum at each time.

#### Output

The number of full steps measured. A step is taken when the pendulum contacts the far switch (x>=l) and then the near switch (x<=0).

#### Test cases

```
8, [8, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 9, 4, 7]
1
```

The pendulum immediately makes contact with the far switch at x=8 at t=0. Then it touches the near switch at t=2 and t=4, completing one step. After that, it touches the far switch again at x=9 at t=8, but it never touches the near switch again.

```
1, [1, 5, -1, -4, -1, 1, -2, 8, 0, -4]
3

15, [10, -7, -13, 19, 0, 22, 8, 9, -6, 21, -14, 12, -5, -12, 5, -3, 5, -15, 0, 2, 11, -11, 12, 5, 16, 14, 27, -5, 13, 0, -7, -2, 11, -8, 27, 15, -10, -10, 4, 21, 29, 21, 2, 5, -7, 15, -7, -14, 13, 27]
7

7, [5, 4, 0]
0

7, [5, 8, 6, 1, 2] 
0
```

Comment: What about `7, [5, 4, 0]`? Is that 0 or 1?  That is - do you assume that a swing is always "full-length"?  Or `7, [5, 8, 6, 1, 2]`?  Is that 0 or 1?

Comment: @NotthatCharles Added.

Comment: I assume a step always is: contact at far end, then near end. That is: near end, then far end is not a full step. So input `8, 
[0 8 0 8]` should give `1`, not `2`. Am I correct?

Comment: @DonMuesli Yes.

Answer (score 4):

### CJam, <s>27</s> 24 bytes

```
l~:Xfe<0fe>_[XT]:Y--Y/,(
```

Input format is the list of pendulum positions followed by `l` on a single line.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l~%3AXfe%3C0fe%3E_%5BXT%5D%3AY--Y%2F%2C(&input=%5B10%20-7%20-13%2019%200%2022%208%209%20-6%2021%20-14%2012%20-5%20-12%205%20-3%205%20-15%200%202%2011%20-11%2012%205%2016%2014%2027%20-5%2013%200%20-7%20-2%2011%20-8%2027%2015%20-10%20-10%204%2021%2029%2021%202%205%20-7%2015%20-7%20-14%2013%2027%5D%2015)

#### Explanation

```
l~     e# Read and evaluate input.
:X     e# Store track length in X.
fe<    e# Clamp each position to X from above.
0f>    e# Clamp each position to 0 from below.
_      e# Duplicate.
[XT]   e# Push the array [X 0].
:Y     e# Store it in Y.
-      e# Set subtraction from the clamped input list. This gives all the
       e# intermediate values.
-      e# Another set subtraction. Remove intermediate values from input list.
Y/     e# Split remaining list around occurrences of ...X 0...
,(     e# Count them and decrement. This is the number of times the pendulum
       e# moved from X to 0.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 22 bytes

```
>~2G0>~-XzY'nw1)0<-H/k
```

This uses [current version (14.0.0)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/14.0.0) of the language/compiler.

Inputs are in the same order and format as in the challenge, separated by a newline.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Pn4yRzA-fi1YelknbncxKTA8LUgvaw&input=MTUKWzEwLCAtNywgLTEzLCAxOSwgMCwgMjIsIDgsIDksIC02LCAyMSwgLTE0LCAxMiwgLTUsIC0xMiwgNSwgLTMsIDUsIC0xNSwgMCwgMiwgMTEsIC0xMSwgMTIsIDUsIDE2LCAxNCwgMjcsIC01LCAxMywgMCwgLTcsIC0yLCAxMSwgLTgsIDI3LCAxNSwgLTEwLCAtMTAsIDQsIDIxLCAyOSwgMjEsIDIsIDUsIC03LCAxNSwgLTcsIC0xNCwgMTMsIDI3XQ)

#### Explanation

```
>~     % take the two inputs implicitly. Generate an array that contains true 
       % where the second input (array of positions) is >= the first input (l)
2G     % push second input (positions) again
0      % push a 0
>~     % true where the second input (array of positions) is <= 0
-      % subtract: array of 1, -1 or 0
Xz     % discard the 0 values
Y'     % run-length encoding: push values and number of repetitions
n      % length of the latter array: number of half-steps, perhaps plus 1
w1)    % swap. Get first element
0<     % true if that element is -1. We need to discard one half-step then
-      % subtract
H/k    % divide by 2 and round down
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript ES6 57 bytes

```
(t,a)=>a.map(a=>a<t?a>0?'':0:1).join``.split`10`.length-1
```

Thanks @NotThatCharles for -4

Comment: Why not split on `/10/`?

Comment: @NotthatCharles I was so sure that didn't work, just tried it and it's great! - thanks

Comment: One Charles to another ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 28 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Run with the input as one long line of space separated integers on STDIN, the first number is the length:

```
perl -p steps.pl <<< "8 8 3 0 1 0 2 2 9 4 7"
```

`steps.pl`:

```
s; ;$'>=$_..$'<1;eg;$_=y;E;
```

Uses the perl flip-flop operator and counts the number of times it returns to false

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 18 bytes

```
/.:@J,Q0m@S+Jd1E2J
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2F.%3A%40J%2CQ0m%40S%2BJd1E2J&input=1%0A%5B1%2C+5%2C+-1%2C+-4%2C+-1%2C+1%2C+-2%2C+8%2C+0%2C+-4%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A%5B1%2C+5%2C+-1%2C+-4%2C+-1%2C+1%2C+-2%2C+8%2C+0%2C+-4%5D%0A15%0A%5B10%2C+-7%2C+-13%2C+19%2C+0%2C+22%2C+8%2C+9%2C+-6%2C+21%2C+-14%2C+12%2C+-5%2C+-12%2C+5%2C+-3%2C+5%2C+-15%2C+0%2C+2%2C+11%2C+-11%2C+12%2C+5%2C+16%2C+14%2C+27%2C+-5%2C+13%2C+0%2C+-7%2C+-2%2C+11%2C+-8%2C+27%2C+15%2C+-10%2C+-10%2C+4%2C+21%2C+29%2C+21%2C+2%2C+5%2C+-7%2C+15%2C+-7%2C+-14%2C+13%2C+27%5D%0A7%0A%5B5%2C+4%2C+0%5D%0A7%0A%5B5%2C+8%2C+6%2C+1%2C+2%5D&debug=0&input_size=2)

Explanation:

```
/.:@J,Q0m@S+Jd1E2J
                      Implicit: Q is the length of the track.
    J,Q0              Set J to [Q, 0]
        m      E      Map over the list
           +Jd        Add the current element to J
          S           Sort
         @    1       Take the middle element.
                      This is the current element, 
                      clamped above by Q and below by 0.
   @J                 Filter for presence in J.
 .:             2     Form 2 element substrings
/                J    Count occurrences of J.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 42

```ruby
->i,a{r=!0
a.count{|v|r^r=v>=i||r&&v>0}/2}
```

`r` starts as `false`. We toggle `r` at each end of the track, and add it to our count.  Then, halve the count (rounding down) to get the number of steps.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 82

Saved 2 bytes thanks to DSM.

Not super golfed yet.

```
def f(x,s):
 c=l=0
 for a in s:
  if a>=x:l=x
  elif a<1:c+=l==x;l*=l!=x
 return c
```

Test cases:

```
assert f(8, [8, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 9, 4, 7]) == 1
assert f(1, [1, 5, -1, -4, -1, 1, -2, 8, 0, -4]) == 3
assert f(15, [10, -7, -13, 19, 0, 22, 8, 9, -6, 21, -14, 12, -5, -12, 5, -3, 5, -15, 0, 2, 11, -11, 12, 5, 16, 14, 27, -5, 13, 0, -7, -2, 11, -8, 27, 15, -10, -10, 4, 21, 29, 21, 2, 5, -7, 15, -7, -14, 13, 27]) == 7
```

Answer (score 0):

## Retina, 34

```
-1*

^(1*)((?>.*?\1.*? \D))*.*
$#2
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LTEqCgpeKDEqKSgoPz4uKj9cMS4qPyBcRCkpKi4qCiQjMg&input=MTExMTExMSwgWzExMTExLCAxMTExLCBd) or [try it with decimal input](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XGQrCiQqCi0xKgoKXigxKikoKD8-Lio_XDEuKj8gXEQpKSouKgokIzI&input=MTUsIFsxMCwgLTcsIC0xMywgMTksIDAsIDIyLCA4LCA5LCAtNiwgMjEsIC0xNCwgMTIsIC01LCAtMTIsIDUsIC0zLCA1LCAtMTUsIDAsIDIsIDExLCAtMTEsIDEyLCA1LCAxNiwgMTQsIDI3LCAtNSwgMTMsIDAsIC03LCAtMiwgMTEsIC04LCAyNywgMTUsIC0xMCwgLTEwLCA0LCAyMSwgMjksIDIxLCAyLCA1LCAtNywgMTUsIC03LCAtMTQsIDEzLCAyN10).

Takes input in unary, negative unary numbers are treated as `-111...` and zero is the empty string. Counts the number of times that the first number appears followed by a zero. Uses an atomic group to guarantee that the matches are minimal (sadly atomic groups are non-capturing so it has to be wrapped in another group...).

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 64 bytes

```
#(count(re-seq #"10"(apply str(for[i %2](condp > i 1 0 %""1)))))
```

Maps values less-than-or-equal of zero to `0`, larger-than-or-equal of length to `1` and others to an empty string `""`. This is then concatenated to a string and occurrences of `"10"` are counted.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 17 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Also known as "how much can I abuse iota-underbar?"

```apl
≢∘∪0~⍨(⍸≤)⍸(⍸0≥⊢)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY@/asNADMZ3P8U3NkPhdGfnznOXZgo0eYFAcRdDunbpEjB2wCEZAp1DC6FL1s55FL2IKykOh/6c9NOnu9V7/fj6sarXb8PA3YnbL25/3Sf35wfu/7j7nkjQ1HH3w9vTZKi42XO/491xNuft5noJ3Bzktnh5Er98ni2GhAoJAQ4k5uWUyBEzkjqhwPVCYrlFzbzQTisZFYpoHrUbQKUqKFBKYQqvPOUgL9GUvAmGm2xh@8gggvVoCuF9NJ4C7uIjlrRFNuxuLtclvjRvqmM/jpuDTGRR3lkI6sYsQdbAZ/p1Z99J/w)